# Как выполнять скрипт только при наличии класса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть скрипт stickUp, который фиксирует меню при скруле и добавляет этому меню класс isStuck, который отвечает за position:fixed. 
У меня есть задача: добавить блок с произвольным содержимым в меню только тогда, когда появляется класс isStuck (когда скрулим страницу и меню фиксируется).

Пытался делать так, не помогло:

```
$('.isStuck').html( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

И так:

```
$('.isStuck').append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

И даже так, но здесь содержимое появляется бесконечно:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 190) {
        $('.isStuck').append( "<p>Test</p>" );
    }
    else {
        $('.isStuck').remove( "<p>Test</p>" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас `if($(this).scrollTop() >= 190)` срабатывает постоянно, и поэтому бесконечно добавление идет.

Если использовать Ваш код, то нужно добавить индикатор того, что блок уже есть.

```
var isStuckBlockAdded = false;

...

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 190) {
         if (!isStuckBlockAdded) {
             isStuckBlockAdded = true;
             $('your-block-selector').append( "<p class="new-block">Test</p>" ); 
             //your-block-selector - селектор для элемента, 
             //в который нужно добавить блок 
             //(убрал .isStuck, т.к. неизвестно к этому моменту будет ли класс уже добавлен)
         }
    }
    else {
         if (isStuckBlockAdded) {
             $('your-block-selector .new-block').remove();  
             //your-block-selector - селектор для элемента, 
             //из которого нужно удалить блок 
             //(убрал .isStuck, т.к. неизвестно к этому моменту не будет ли класс уже удален)
             isStuckBlockAdded = false;
         }
    }
});
```

---

Хотя я бы предложил события использовать

```
var Events = {
    StuckClassAdded = "StuckClassAdded"
};
...

//Где-то в инициализации
$(Events).on(Events.StuckClassAdded, function() {
   $('.isStuck').append( "<p>Test</p>" );
});

... 
// Там где добавляете класс
$(Events).trigger(Events.StuckClassAdded);
...
```

Удаление сделать аналогично.

Comment: в примере нигде не выставляется _isStuckBlockAdded_ - этот флаг всегда false

Comment: @Grundy извиняюсь, пропустил. Спасибо за замечание. Получился и правда горе советчик :-) Поправил.

Comment: Первый вариант не удаляет.
Второй вариант не работает.

Comment: @Александр, да, извиняюсь, снова проглядел, конечно же `$('.isStuck')` не будет работать, т.к. вы к этому времени скорее всего удалили уже класс, попробуйте свой селектор другой использовать, которым можно идентифицировать элемент. По второму варианту, нужно смотреть как у Вас сделано, это всего лишь рекомендация.